# sharepoint 2010 standard edition - workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Can I design a workflow in  SharePoint 2010 Standard edition? Or this is only available in the enterprise edition?

I can not find a template for the workflow

Answer (score 1):

The [workflow feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263148(v=office.14).aspx) in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 enables solution architects, designers, and administrators to improve business processes.

[Workflow features are available in both standard and enterprise](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2010/compare-sharepoint-server-enterprise/).

Now you have 4 options to [create workflow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263308(v=office.14).aspx):

1. Use the OOTB worflows
2. [Create the workflows using the SharePoint designer 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx)
3. [Create workflow using the Visual studio.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231606(v=vs.100).aspx)
4. Or you can use 3rd party solutions for workflows i.e nintex.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Sharepoint Designer 2010?
There is workflow creation tool.
Try it, if you haven't! 
Good luck!